# How to render dynamic generated key in mustache

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

I have a json data with fields. I want to render it in mustache js. But the problem is one of the item in the list is generating dynamically. How can I iterate this item.

I used the given code

```
 '{{#view}}{{#.}}<td class="number">{{.}}</td>{{/.}}{{/view}}' +
 '{{#comment}}{{#.}}<td class="number">{{.}}</td>{{/.}}{{/comment}}' +
 '{{#rating}}{{#.}}<td class="number">{{.}}</td>{{/.}}{{/rating}}' +
```

But it rendering as [object object]

[image: Json array format]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` is only for iterating through an array of strings, so your template will not work. However, you can always process/modify your data before parsing it to the template:

```
for (key in data){
  if (key == 'comment' || key == 'rating' || key == 'view'){
     //Turn it into an array
     var temp_array = [];
     for (key2 in data[key]){
       // To make sure it is not a function or __proto__ object whatsoever
       if (typeof data[key][key2] != "object" && typeof data[key][key2] != "function") {
         temp_array.push(data[key][key2]);
       }
     }
     data[key] = temp_array;
  }
}
```

To change the item list into an array and then parse to the template.

Hope this help.

Comment: so you are saying the result must must modify first.. right??

Comment: as far as I know, yes. Mustache does not have any support to literate through objects

Comment: I need a help. My json is changed, must need a clarification for this. Please help

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: please look in to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144428/how-to-convert-json-from-one-format-to-another